# Creational adapter

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, refactoring

I have a lot of code like this

```
additional_params = {
  date_issued: pending.present? ? pending.date_issued : Time.current,
  gift_status: status,
  date_played: status == "Opened" ? Chronic.parse("now") : (opened.present? ? opened.date_played : nil),
  email_template: service&.email_template,
  email_text: service&.email_text,
  email_subject: service&.email_subject,
  label: service&.label,
  vendor_confirmation_code: service&.vendor_confirmation_code
}
SomeService.new(reward, employee: employee, **additional_params).create
```

The same pattern applies to many models and services.

What is the name of this pattern?

How to refactor the current solution?

Is there a gem to solve this kind of solution? Like [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) or something else

Comment: What pattern do you mean, exactly?

Comment: As you can see in the provided code, there's some transformation from input data into parameters for `SomeService` model. I can't figure out what is the name of such pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, that looks a bit like a god object for every type of entity. You expect your service to take care of everything related to your entity. The entity itself just acts as a data container and isn't responsible for its data. That's called an anemic model.

First of all, you need to understand that there can be several representations of the same entity. You can have several different classes that represent a user. On the "List user" page, the class contains just a subset of the information, maybe combined with information from the account system (last login, login attempt etc). On the user registration page, you have another class as it's not valid to supply all information for the user.

Those classes are called data transfer objects. Their purpose is to provide the information required for a specific use case and to decouple the internal entity from the external API (i.e. the web page).

Once you have done that, your service classes will start to shrink and you need fewer custom parameters for every method call.

Now your service class has two responsibilities: To manage all entities and to be responsible for their business rules.

To solve that, you should start to only modify your entities through behaviors (methods) and never update the fields directly. When you do so, you will automatically move logic from your service class to your entity class.

Once that is done, your service classes will be even cleaner.

You can read about Domain Driven Design to get inspired (no need to use DDD, but get inspired by how the application layer is structured in it).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the builder pattern. I am not familiar with a ruby gem, but you can find information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface